# Whats wrong in my code?

Tags: java

I seems like I cant skip over the while loop as my code does not understand that I typed in the right number.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class HelloWorld1{
     static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      static int randomNumbe

 public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(randomNum());
    int randomGuess = -1 ;
    while(randomGuess != randomNum()){
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 to 100");
        randomGuess = userInput.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Yes the random number is:" + randomGuess);
}

public static int randomNum(){
    randomNumber = (int) (Math.random()*101);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't print the number anywhere. Are you using a debugger? Because if you can guess a random number without any clues, I think you have a better career to be following... In other words: the random number is changing every iteration. How do you know it's right?

Answer (score 0):

When you call randomNum(), you're getting another random value back. Try:

```
int expected = randomNum();
System.out.println(expected);
int guess = -1;
while(guess != expected) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package randomguess;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomGuess {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

static int randomNumber = 0;

public static int getRandomInt() {
    randomNumber = (int) (Math.random()*101);
    return randomNumber;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int guessInt = sc.nextInt();
    int randomInt = getRandomInt();

    while(guessInt != randomInt) {
        System.out.println("Better luck nextTime :D Random number was "+randomInt);
        guessInt = sc.nextInt();
        randomInt = getRandomInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Yeah! You are oracle!");
  }
}
```

Here is probably what you want. Let me know if it is.

Comment: And why should that be what he wants? Some explanations should be great for OP.

Comment: @Tom i thought he was asking for the solution. Here it is. He can compare codes and find out where the mistakes are.